# Length of Version field in IP Datagram header

Tags: ip, tcp

I have doubt regarding length of "version" field in IP datagram. I have read the possible values are either 4 or 6 but they can represented in binary as 100 and 110, which are 3 bits in length. Then why the field has 4 bit length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, that's the way it's been defined. It also leaves some space for future versions. IPv15 - hmm...

Comment: Well, some of the values are reserved, so one of the reserved values can, in the future, mean that the version number is now longer than four bits. This is another one of the IANA number lists: _[Version Numbers](https://www.iana.org/assignments/version-numbers/version-numbers.xhtml)_.